# How to understand chats.html v.s ('/getchats', ChatsRequestHandler)]

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I try to understand the different between:

The class ChatsRequestHandler generate a template with the name chats.html

```
template = self.generate('chats.html', template_values)
```

In the application view its is named getchats:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                     [('/', MainRequestHandler),
                      ('/getchats', ChatsRequestHandler)],
```

The same occurs to me at **edit_user.html** v.s ('/**edituser**', EditUserProfileHandler)

How is it that the application knows that the getchats is connected to the chats.html aldo they have not the same name? I would expect that it should be the same name chats.html and     ('/chats', ChatsRequestHandler).

Comment: What I found there is a javaschript function updateChat().     function updateChat() {downloadUrl(getRandomUrl("/getchats"), "GET", null, onChatsReturned);}. By this my question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your request goes something like this.

1. App Engine looks up your app.yaml file. It should contain an entry that says `/getchats` should be handled by `application` in `somefile.py`.
2. It then goes to this "application view" and matches it to a Webapp Route. In this case, that route is `('/getchats', ChatsRequestHandler)`.
3. Then it calls `get` or `post` on ChatRequestHandler, passing it the request and response objects.
4. The output of that is sent back to the user's browser.

You are free to implement `ChatRequestHandler` as you'd like. In this case you're doing so by reading in a template named `chats.html`, populating it with some values, and then outputting it.

So the application knows that getchats is connected to ChatRequestHandler. The name of chats.html is pretty arbitrary - the ChatReqeustHandler has to know it, but that is all. You could rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me:

The example a came up with comes from codenvy.com as a examples app.

1 App Engine looks up your app.yaml file. It should contain an entry that says /getchats should be handled by application in somefile.py.

Here is the app.yaml file of this application

```
application: 3kus-apps
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /.*
  script: devchat.py
```

So as you can see it contain's no entry that says /getchats should be handled by application in somefile.py.

What i found there is a util.js file witch has a function updateChat(). function updateChat() {downloadUrl(getRandomUrl("/getchats"), "GET", null, onChatsReturned);}.

However, I would like to know - under (1) how this should be handled by a somefile.py.

Comment: The handler `url: /.*` means all urls that start with / `.` is a wildcard for any character and `*` means '0 or more times'. So `.*` is a any pattern (including blank). It's a Regular Expression.